# NullReferenceException when accessing GUI Components in Controllers constructor

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monomac

In Mono I have a simple NSWindow with Controller on it I drop a NSSplitView and a NSButton.

If I try to access the NSSplitView out of the Contstructor or `Initialize()` Method I get a nullReferenceException. Instead if I try to access the NSSplitView from a ButtonClicked Method, it works.

Well, it seems that the Framework creates the GUI Components after the controller's Construtor is called. But where should I put my code to configure GUI Components if not in the Constructor?

Thanks in advance.
Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `AwakeFromNib` method in your controller class. It is called once all the objects have been loaded and properly connected.

```
public override void AwakeFromNib ()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib ();

    // Do something here with the outlets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {
    base.ViewDidLoad();
}
```

for configuring your view because that's the method which is called when the view just loaded, not when you instantiated the controller. If you configure your view in `AwakeFromNib()` you'll force the instantiation of your view whereas you maybe don't need them now. Indeed, when you create a controller the view are not created until someone try to access viewController.View.